# Testing multiple wordpress sites without a domain name

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to install wordpress without a domain name such as

Eg.-

```
182.28.91.19/wp-login.php

sample.182.28.91.19/wp-login.php
```

Something like that ?

I need to sort out some wordpress performance issues and for that i need to test those in a live environment but without using a domain name.

Comment: You mean install wordpress locally and accessing it from your machine?

Comment: @Nick nope. that's the ip address of the vps(droplet / instance of the ip) created at your hosting provider